# Implementing database constraints that are not possible to ensure with the DDL of RDBMS

Tags: database, sqlite, constraints

This is a homework question, but it doesn't particularly make sense to me:

"How will you implement the constraints for your database that will not be possible to ensure with the mechanism of the Data Definition Language of RDBMS".

Aren't all constraints defined by the DDL when you're creating the tables?

Comment: I think this question can be understood only when you know the expected answer. "Use CHECK constraints" or "use triggers" or "do it in the application" or "don't check" are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Aren't all constraints defined by the DDL when you're creating the
>   tables?

Only if you interpret "constraints" to mean those limitations that can be handled by CONSTRAINT definitions in your chosen RDBMS.

A better way to phrase the question, as I interpret its meaning, might be:
How will you enforce any data integrity rules that are too complex for a simple constraint to handle?